# How can I convert a number to a string, the contents of which depend on the number's factors.?

Tags: java, string, int, factors

[code that I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu4ty.png) If the number has 3 as a factor, output 'a statement'.
If the number has 5 as a factor, output 'another statement'.
If the number has 7 as a factor, output 'another statement'.
If the number does not have 3, 5, or 7 as a factor, just pass the number's digits straight through. I don't understand how to do it. I wast trying to use for loop and if else statements to solve this but I couldn't do it... Please help me through this.

Comment: Looks like FizzBuzz

Answer (score 1):

For positive integers use something like this:

```
if (( number % 3  ) == 0 ) {
  System.out.println( "a statement" );
}
if ((( number % 5  ) == 0 ) || (( number % 7 ) == 0 )) {
  System.out.println( "another statement" );
}
```

Could your describe what you want to achieve? What is the usage for this? Maybe there are much better solutions. The percent char is Javas "remainder" operator.

Comment: If I give 28 and 28's factors are 1, 2, 4, 7, 14, 28. If it is 7 I want to output "Plong".